# Regexp split multiline by delimiter

Tags: regex

I have a multiple line text file which have blocks of text. Each block starts with `name=`, block can have variable number of lines. I need to extract these blocks, including `name=`.
Here is my best idea so far:

```
/(name=.*?)/gs
```

But it only matches the begging of the block `name=`, not the whole block.

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB4lD3/1)

Comment: What language/platform/flavor?

Comment: @Jessen I suppose it may be Perl.

Comment: I didn't specify I guess it's common for all languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(name=.*?)(?=name=|$)/gs
```

You need to give your regex someway to stop. So include a `lookahead` which would stop regex at next instance of `next=` or `end of string`.